# Upload larger file to server not working

Tags: php, upload, server

I got a problem here about upload larger file in my server.I go through a lot of related questions here but i still got the same problem. I increase all the necessary php.ini in the server and when i upload larger file for only 38MB the system cannot upload it.What i do wrong here. Please help Thanks in advance.

```
$allowedExts = array("mp4", "MP4");
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/MP4"))

&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))

  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists('/home/hyborg/public_html/vimeo2/upload/' . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], '/home/hyborg/public_html/vimeo2/upload/' . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Upload Success" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Sorry something wrong with your upload";
  }
```

Comment: did u set all prameters like: php_value upload_max_filesize 50M
php_value post_max_size 50M
php_value max_input_time 300
php_value max_execution_time 300

Comment: add some code which related to your question, else you will get down vote fore **Low Quality Question**

Comment: sorry about that. i increase it to 1024M but still not working

Comment: i edit back the question

Comment: Why not check your error log or turn on `display_errors` to see what useful error information PHP is giving you rather than guessing?

Comment: i got this error
[14-Jul-2015 05:22:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of 26107543 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 0):

Did you make all the appropriate changes?
`upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`

Also you should change the `max_input_time`  ,as upload.PHP scripts normally time-out after 30 seconds.For larger files to upload it takes much time.Try increasing the `max_execution_time` to something like 500 (in sec).

Then you have to define the constraints within your PHP application:

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '10M');
ini_set('max_input_time', 300);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

PHP also provides a set_time_limit() function so you don’t need to set max_execution_time directly.

Setting the options in your PHP code is possibly more practical, since you can extend the execution time and increase the file size when your application is expecting a large upload.

Comment: thanks again for the reply..actually i increase all of it to
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '1024M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '1024M');
ini_set('max_input_time', 1024);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 1024);

Comment: try this : `if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/MP4"))
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts) &&  ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 100000))` Just specify the size as you require.